# Объединение стилей в консоли разработчика в Chrome.

Tags: css, google-chrome, консоль

Подскажите, есть ли возможность как-то отключить в консоли разработчика объединение разных классов в один, если у них одинаковые стили? На фото яркий пример, когда элементы и находятся в разных местах, и называются по разному да и по сути они вообще разные, но в консоли если менять стили, то они применяются сразу к обоим элементам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы применяете стили к классу, следовательно все элементы с этим классом обновляют стили. Это правильное поведение

Comment: Каво? У вас два сотрудника, вы поручили им одинаковое задание, а теперь спрашиваете почему они выполняют одно задание.

Comment: Ну и да, чтобы в консоли работать, нажмите на "плюсик" и у вас появится как бы отдельный класс под элемент.

Comment: Да, я дал РАЗНЫМ сотрудникам одно и тоже задание, но я не хотел их садить за один и тот же стол! Пусть у меня 2к монитор, в консоли ещё куча свободного места внизу, пусть они сядут за разные столы. Это глупо всё запихивать в одно место. Точнее глупо не дать возможности разъединить нам все классы по отдельности. 
В качестве примера: есть блок, в котором родитель display: flex и column, а в нём куча элементов, которые тоже flex, но при этом row. Так вот в консоли они всё-равно объединены. И при изменении flex-direction там такая каша происходит...

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы в консоли разработчика работать с "объединёнными классами" по отдельности, сделайте следующее.

Выберите тот класс, который нужен и скопируйте его.

[image: Нужный класс]

Далее найдите там иконку плюса и нажмите на неё, далее заменив "созданный класс" на тот, что скопировали.

[image: Вставка класс]

И нажав внутри скобок вписывайте нужные стили

[image: Стили]

---

На скринах консоль Лисы, но уверен, что в гугле всё точно так же.